# using WebClient class to return image data and render the image in a tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, image

I have a GenericHandler page which makes use of the WebClient class in ASP.

If i wanted to load an image into an image tag, i wasnt sure how i should do it.  I tried:

```
<img src="handler.asxh?url=http://somesite.com&contentType=image" />
```

but that didnt return a successful image because the handler isnt return a path to the object, but instead downloading the DATA for it.

With that said:  I have a bunch of data, representing said image just no way for me to get it into a tag.

Im using authentication to get into a webserver to scoop an image stored in there, and it does exactly what i want, but the images themselves are zipped and hidden in a database which is not outward facing, so just doing that does not seem to work.

What should be done?

**EDIT:  Handler Implementation**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context){
  WebClient wsb = new WebClient();
  string url = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
  string content = context.Request.QueryString["contentType"];
  string response = wsb.DownloadString(url);
  context.Response.ContentType = content;
  context.Response.Write(response);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** This is used for doing CORS involving older browsers which do not support it.  Use the generic handler, and in this case, write out a byte array to the client and you can just pass in hashed auth tokens via URL and then parse and place into WebClient classes headers.

Comment: Show implementation of the handler.

Comment: @EugeneS. just added a quick and dirty implementation.  I use it to obtain json data from servers requiring authentication etc... so there CAN be other params related to header data.  Nevertheless, this shorter version is all that would be needed to do the Process for the obtained image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be downloading the image as a string. However, an image is Binary data that can not be easily stored in a string (excluding base64 or other transformations).
You should be downloading the image as a byte array.

Then you can use the `response.BinaryWrite(byteArray)`-method to send the data to the client.
Code below is not tested, but should point you in the right direction:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context){
  WebClient wsb = new WebClient();
  string url = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
  string content = context.Request.QueryString["contentType"];
  byte[] response = wsb.DownloadData(url);
  context.Response.ContentType = content;
  context.Response.BinaryWrite(response);
}
```

Comment: ahhh, ok.   So, maybe it would be smart of me to instead of setting the content type to image, check if content type is IMAGE and then if YES, write binary out?  That way, i can still use it for things which return strings, such as, but not limited to returning JSON, strings, xml, etc.

Comment: @Fallenreaper That would indeed be an option. That way you also have a limited list of allowed content-types instead of allowing everything the client throws at you. In my opinion it would be better to use a fixed content type (image), and make separate handlers for other data...

Comment: Good to know.  Thank you.   I will try this out and see what happens.  Ill give you an update shortly for confirmation.

Comment: Confirmed.    You just write out the byte[] and place it directly into the src tag renders the image.  Doing this intermediate step allows CORS in Older Browsers.